# Parsing Mixed Types in Fsharp.Data JsonProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a JSON input I want to parse in F# using Fsharp.Data, it looks like this:-

```
[
    {
        "Server": "ServerName1",
        "CNAME": [ "cname1", "cname2"]
    },
    {
        "Server": "ServerName2",
        "CNAME": {}
    }
]
```

Note the way an empty array is returned as {} rather than [], unfortunately I can't change this.

When I parse this with Fsharp.Data the CName property is of type ArrayOrCname (which makes sense).

How do I determine in F# whether I have an Array or an empty CName record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated type `ArrayOrCname` should have two properties - `Record` and `Array` - which are both optional. If the value is a record, the first one will be `Some` and the other will be `None` and vice versa for an array. So, you can handle this using pattern matching. Using your example:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
open FSharp.Data

type T = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<"""[
  { "Server": "ServerName1",
    "CNAME": [ "cname1", "cname2"] },
  { "Server": "ServerName2",
    "CNAME": {} } ]""">
```

We can now get sample data (just to test this) and pattern match on the properties of `Cname`:

```
let servers = T.GetSamples()
for server in servers do
  match server.Cname.Record, server.Cname.Array with
  | Some recd, _ -> 
      printfn "empty record"
  | _, Some arr ->
      printfn "names: %A" arr
  | _ -> 
      failwith "This should never happen"
```

If you just want to know whether the value is an array or not, you could define a simple helper that turns `ArrayOrCname` into an option:

```
let asOption (v:T.ArrayOrCname) = 
  match v.Record, v.Array with
  | _, Some arr -> Some arr
  | _ -> None
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was on the right track but hadn't quite pulled it together this way

Comment: No problem! In an idal world, the type `ArrayOrCname` would itself be a discriminated union, but unfortunately, type providers cannot generate DUs and so it has to be a bit odd type with optional properties.